# why MongoDB logging didn't write all the query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

### MongoDB logging didn't write all the query.

for example I have following query at express.js using mongoose to call mongo database.

```
  myCollection.findOne({ }, function (err, result1) {
        myCollection2.findOne({ }, function (err, result2) {
            myCollection3.findOne({ }, function(err, result3){
}
```

when I look up the logfile, I can see following as there's myCollection3 query talk to mongo db. But there's no myCollection & myCollection2 at the file. Is this a default behavior of mongo logging?

myCollection3 query......

Comment: Could you provide more information? Do you have profiling on? What level? What verbosity level is the server running at? Can you show us what the log says vs. what you expect it to say?

Comment: I set db.setProfilingLevel(2,0), means showing all query & any query long than 0ms(I guess). This should be showing every query. However when I look at it, I was expecting showing something like following.  myCollection 1ms; myCollection2 2ms; myCollection3 2ms; however it actually showing myCollection3 *ms.

Answer (score 0):

Profiling doesn't output to the logs. It outputs to the system.profile collection of the database. In `db.setProfilingLevel(level, slowMS)`, `slowMS` is the number of milliseconds that a querys execution time must exceed before it is logged to the log. But 1 is the smallest meaningful value for `slowMS`. With the profiling level at 2, all queries will be in the system.profile collection, so look there instead.